# Highchart Pie chart with partially colored slices

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I was wondering if it's possible to create a pie chart where each slice is partially colored in order to denote how "complete" (in %) that slice is.

It's probably better to explain with an example.

[image: Colored pie chart example]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at using a **polar chart** (see http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar).

Try working with the "column" series in the Highcharts demo as your starting point; that's the version that should get you closest to what you're looking to achieve. You can make each of the points a different color to match your example.

**Update (May 29, 2016):** I worked up a sample fiddle based strictly on your example image: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/uzna0mk6/

Here's the code I modified from Highcharts' polar chart demo. It's not 100% perfect, as the wedge labels will be tricky to format as in your example image, but this should get you pretty far.

I hope this helps!

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { polar: true },
        title: { text: 'Highcharts polar chart with colored wedges' },
        legend: { enabled: false },
                plotOptions: {
                // starts the chart at the 12-o-clock position
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        },
        xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
            categories: ['series A','series B','series C','series D','series E'],
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0, max: 100,
            labels: { enabled: false }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  inside: true,
                  verticalAlign: 'middle'
                },
                // keeps the pie wedges joined together
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0,
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'background fill for the wedges',
            data: [18,30,45,47,5],
            color: '#BCBCBC',
            enableMouseTracking: false, // prevent the user from interacting with this series
            dataLabels: { enabled: false }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'wedge value',
            data: [
                // each slice of the pie gets its own color
                { y: 82, color: 'blue' },
              { y: 70, color: 'purple' },
              { y: 55, color: 'orange' },
              { y: 53, color: 'yellow' },
              { y: 95, color: 'green' }
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Brightmatrix. I saw it originally but discarded it because my "slices of the pie" aren't all of the same size which I thought was a requirement for the polar chart. Did I get that wrong?

Comment: @jeromeso The good news is that your slices don't need to be the same size for a polar chart. This is why I suggested this chart type to you ... what you have here is really a column chart resized to form pie wedges. I can set up a working fiddle from that image, if you like.

Comment: Thanks, Brightmatrix. That'd be great if you could show me the way to do it w/ a quick fiddle example!

Comment: @jeromeso I've updated my answer with the working fiddle and some additional explanations. Please let me know if this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much, Brightmatrix! That looks great. What I can't figure out is how to make the angle of the "slices of the pie" different. Given that the whole pie is 100%, given the colors above the breakdown should be blue   = 20%
pink   = 15%
orange = 30%
yellow = 15%
green  = 20%
How do I achieve that?

Comment: I see that I misread your original question slightly, @jeromeso. Just so I'm clear: you want a pie whose slices are a percentage of 100, and the depth/size of the slices are also a percentage of the distance from the center to the edge, as in my current answer. Is that correct?

Comment: brightmatrix, you tackled the distance-to-center aspect perfectly in your example but I also need to vary the angle/width of each slice to reflect that some of the slices are more important than others.

Comment: @JeromeProvensal I don't think it's possible to do both. The wedges of a polar chart are equal to one another in size. That size is defined by how many there are, whether that's categories as in my example, or degrees as in the demos. I unfortunately don't see a way to widen or contract them individually based on a separate value.

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion, unfortunately. Still, thank you very much for your help @brightmatrix!